# React Ref objects reset itself after second call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-ref

Hi im trying to develop a program which uses ref.

```
 let cardsRef = useRef([]);
```

im creating ref in the useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    cardsRef.current = cards.map((_ref, index) => {
      return cardsRef.current[index] = createRef();
    });
    setInitialize(true);
  }, [cards, isShuffled]);

return (
{cards.map(item => {
        return (
          <div key={item.id}  ref={cardsRef.current[item.id]}>
            {item.value}
          </div>
        );
      })}
)
```

but when i change cards array in the

```
  const shuffleArray = (array) => {
    let tempArr = [];
    tempArr = array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    setCards(tempArr);
    setIsShuffled(true);
  };
```

React cant find cardsRef.current[index].current.
Beacuse shuffleArray function resets cardsRef array ? I guess.

Thank your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are some things to note here...

1. `createRef` is only used in class components. It's the class equivalent of `useRef`, which you've used at the top.
2. You should not be trying to set new refs inside an effect hook. You do this in the component's main scope.
3. Remember that changing the `current` value on a ref will not cause a re-render. I think you want to use state here instead. Think of ref values as places to store data you need but which should not cause the UI to refresh when it changes.

I can explain more if you need... let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but then how can i add dynamic array ref ? 
I was following https://adebola-niran.medium.com/how-to-create-multiple-refs-in-react-with-useref-5fa2bbef5d15

Comment: i'm not sure what you're trying to do where you're mapping your cards. What are you trying to achieve that wouldn't happen if you just did `cardsRef.current = cards`?

Comment: okey done it thank you 
i made 2 mistake 
1 createRef()
2 return map was wrong
but your first and second comments help me a lot thank you

Comment: maybe someone is trying to generate dynamic ref array thats why im leaving my source 

  let cardsRef = useRef([]);

{cards.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}  ref={cardsRef.current[index] = item}>
             {item.value}
          </div>
        );
      })}